# How to avoid committing .gitignore file in Eclipse Egit

Tags: eclipse, git

I have a file on my local branch that I have added to the .gitignore file that is shipped with Ecipse git(Egit) but each time I try to commit and push that branch to the remote branch, I see my .gitignore showing as one of the files that has been changed as well as the file I added to the .gitignore file. How can I untrack these two so that only files I really want to commit and push to the central repo are visible when I go to the team->commit in eclipse?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you should add `.gitignore` to your `.gitignore` file, then `git add .gitignore` and `git commit` to commit it.  I know you didn't want to touch other files, but this is the best way to go about things.  You can always make another branch later and cherry-pick the commits that you want to push into it (without the one that touched `.gitignore`) before you push to the remote repository.

Answer (score 0):

There are certain things you need to understand first:
 1. A file once committed in the repository cannot be marked as untracked unless its deleted from the repository and the deletion is committed. (Not advised in your case)
 2. When you add something to .gitignore since its already in source control it "will" show as modified. The other file that you have is also committed in the repository hence it shows it also as modified.
What can you do?
If you are sure that the file you want to ignore should not be part of version control then delete it, commit and push the deletion.
Then you can ignore the file in two ways:
 3. Use .gitignore: Add that file in .gitignore and commit and push it so that others also don't face this problem
 4. Add the file name in your local .git/info.exclude file

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks guys. The only problem is I am not allowed to commit the file and I don't want to commit .gitIgnore as that file is used by others and my changes are only personal and needed for my use alone.

Comment: In that case IF "that file" is not already committed by you or someone else then you could add it to .git/info/exclude and you will be done. If it has been already committed to repo by you or someone else then there is nothing you can do to untrack it except deleting it and committing its deletion.